# Issue importing transfer journal through x++

Tags: axapta, x++

I have the following problem: the following code works perfectly:

```
inventJournalTrans.clear();
inventJournalTrans.initFromInventJournalTable(inventJournalTable);
inventJournalTrans.ItemId = "100836M";

frominventDim.InventLocationId="SD";
frominventDim.wMSLocationId = '11_RECEPTION';
fromInventDim.InventSizeId = '1000';
fromInventDim.inventBatchId = 'ID057828-CN';

ToinventDim.InventLocationId = "SD";
ToInventDim.wMSLocationId = '11_A2';
ToInventDim.InventSizeId = '1000';
ToInventDim.inventBatchId = 'T20/0001/1';

ToinventDim = InventDim::findOrCreate(ToinventDim);
frominventDim = InventDim::findOrCreate(frominventDim);

inventJournalTrans.InventDimId = frominventDim.inventDimId;
inventJournalTrans.initFromInventTable(InventTable::find("100836M"));
inventJournalTrans.Qty = -0.5;
inventJournalTrans.ToInventDimId = ToinventDim.inventDimId;
inventJournalTrans.CostAmount = InventJournalTrans.calcCostAmount(-abs(any2real(strReplace('-0.5',',','.'))));
inventJournalTrans.TransDate = SystemDateget();
inventJournalTrans.insert();

inventJournalCheckPost = InventJournalCheckPost::newJournalCheckPost(JournalCheckpostType::Post,inventJournalTable);
inventJournalCheckPost.parmThrowCheckFailed(_throwserror);
inventJournalCheckPost.parmShowInfoResult(_showinforesult);
inventJournalCheckPost.run();
```

It creates transfer journal line correctly and posts the transfer journal successfully.

My requirement is to import journal lines from a csv file. I wrote the following code:

```
    inventJournalTrans.clear();
    inventJournalTrans.initFromInventJournalTable(inventJournalTable::find(_journalID));
    InventJournaltrans.ItemId             = conpeek(_filerecord,4);

    inventDim_From.InventLocationId       = 'SD';
    inventDim_From.wMSLocationId          = '11_RECEPTION';
    InventDim_from.InventSizeId           = conpeek(_fileRecord,11);
    InventDim_From.inventBatchId          = strfmt("%1",conpeek(_fileRecord,5));

    InventDim_To.InventLocationId         = 'SD';
    inventDim_To.wMSLocationId            = strfmt("%1",conpeek(_fileRecord,10));
    InventDim_To.InventSizeId             = conpeek(_fileRecord,11);
    InventDim_To.inventBatchId            = strfmt("%1",conpeek(_fileRecord,6));

    InventDim_From                        = InventDim::findOrCreate(inventDim_From);
    inventDim_To                          = InventDim::findOrCreate(inventDim_To);

    InventJournalTrans.InventDimId = inventDim_From.inventDimId;
    InventJournalTrans.initFromInventTable(InventTable::find(conpeek(_filerecord,4)));
    inventJournalTrans.Qty                = -abs(any2real(strReplace(conpeek(_fileRecord,8),',','.')));
    inventJournalTrans.ToInventDimId      = inventDim_To.inventDimId;
    InventJournalTrans.CostAmount         = InventJournalTrans.calcCostAmount(-abs(any2real(strReplace(conpeek(_fileRecord,8),',','.'))));
    inventJournalTrans.TransDate          = str2date(conpeek(filerecord,9),123);
    InventJournalTrans.insert();
```

I have the following error when I use the insert() method : size does not exists for the itemId. When I have a look in inventSize table for my itemId, the size exists, I thought it was an inventDimId problem in inventJournalTrans but they're strictly similar to the first code exemple. All my datas are the same as the first exemple but are not hard-coded and come from reading my csv file.

I spend a lot of time debugging and found nothing wrong but error message remains
I'm using Dynamics AX V4 SP1.
Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Are you sure that the ItemId is being retrieved as expected from the file?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Have you tried the following while debugging: First, replace all the values in the code that reads the csv file with hard coded values so that it works. Then, one by one, replace the values with the values from the csv file. Check after each replacement that the code still works. This way, you can identify which value causes the issue. Then, write the value into a separate variable and compare it with a variable that holds the hardcoded value. Compare the two values in code to make sure they are equal. And just as a wild guess: check that there are no encoding issues with the csv file.

Comment: The second to last line, you have `inventJournalTrans.TransDate          = str2date(conpeek(filerecord,9),123);`. Should it be `_filerecord` and not `filerecord`?

Is this AX 2009 or 2012?

Comment: While debugging, throw a `conView(_filerecord)` at the top, and use that to verify the contents of the CSV data. It sounds like you have an invalid Item+Size combination, so while the size may exist, it may not be valid for that item.

Comment: I'm using Dynamics AX V4 SP1

Comment: replace filerecord by _filerecord, nothing new

Comment: @Alex : values displayed in conview are correct, item size combination is correctly created and is the same as the csv Data

Comment: The problem is in the following line: InventDim_To.InventSizeId             = conpeek(_fileRecord,11);

Answer (score 0):

When you read from files always trim trailing spaces. You can do that using the [strRtrim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-string-run-time-functions#strrtrim) function.

Like so:

```
InventDim_To.InventSizeId = strRtrim(conpeek(_fileRecord,11));
```

Comment: In addition, check out `strLRtrim()`, and do a `if(InventSize::Exists(conPeek(_fileRecord, 11)))` for a sanity check. If that returns false, you know the size does not exist and contains a special character.